# Extract first X digits of N digit numbers

Tags: r, substr

How to select first 2 digits of a number? I just need the name of the function

Example:   12455 turns into 12, 13655 into 13

Basically it's the equivalent of substring for integers.

Answer (score 8):

If at the end you need again a numeric vector/element, you can use

```
as.numeric(substr(x, 1, 2))
```

Comment: You're right, I used `as.character` because in the docs is written that `substr` wants a character vector, but actually the function uses `as.character` internally. I edit my answer in order to use less code. Thank you @DarrenTsai

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses `gsub`, the anchor `^` signifiying the start position of a string, `\\d{2}` for any two digits appearing at this position, wrapped into `(...)` to mark it as a capturing group, and backreference `\\1` in the replacement argument, which 'recalls' the capturing group:

```
x <- c(12455,13655)

gsub("(^\\d{2}).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "12" "13"
```

Alternatively, use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "^\\d{2}")
```